# Ext.NET not integrating with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net

I created a MVC 4 web application in VS 2012.
Downloaded Ext.Net 2 via NuGet.
In my view/home/index.cshtml file, I am trying to type :

```
@Html.X().ResourceManager()
```

I am getting the following when I run:

> CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'X' and no extension method 'X' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here's my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="extnet" type="Ext.Net.GlobalConfig" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication3-20121016104640;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication3-20121016104640.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ext" namespace="Ext.Net" assembly="Ext.Net" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*/ext.axd" verb="*" type="Ext.Net.ResourceHandler" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DirectRequestModule" type="Ext.Net.DirectRequestModule, Ext.Net" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="DirectRequestHandler" verb="*" path="*/ext.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Ext.Net.ResourceHandler" />
      <add name="ExtNetHandler" path="*/ext.axd" verb="*" type="Ext.Net.ResourceHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add name="DirectRequestModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="Ext.Net.DirectRequestModule, Ext.Net" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.5.7" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Ext.Net.Utilities" publicKeyToken="2c34ac34702a3c23" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0" newVersion="2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <extnet theme="Gray" />
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Add Ext.Net to assemblies in `<system.web>`

   ```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
         <assemblies>
           ....
             <add assembly="Ext.Net"/>
         </assemblies>
    </compilation>
   ```
2. Add namespaces in `<system.web>`

   ```
   <pages>
     <namespaces>
        ....
       <add namespace="Ext.Net"/>
       <add namespace="Ext.Net.MVC"/>
     </namespaces>
   </pages>
   ```
3. Correct assemblyBinding like in geoffrey.mcgill post
4. Add namespaces in web.config in Views folder (in `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section)

   ```
   <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
       <namespaces>
          ....
          <add namespace="Ext.Net" />
          <add namespace="Ext.Net.MVC" />
       </namespaces>
    </pages>
   ```
5. Add Ext.Net assembly in web.config in Views folder (in `<system.web>` section)

   ```
    <pages ....>
       <controls>
           ....
          <add assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagPrefix="ext" />
       </controls>
    </pages>
   ```

Comment: The namespace Ext.Net.MVC does not exist any more in the latest version of ext.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that you added the proper Reference to the Ext.Net.dll in your project?

Edit: I believe your `<runtime>` node inside of `<system.webserver>` is incorrect. Should be the following, where each Assembly is defined as a separate `<assemblyBinding>`.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.5.7" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Ext.Net.Utilities" publicKeyToken="2c34ac34702a3c23" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0" newVersion="2.0.1" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I believe there might be a defect in NuGet. We've seen other reports of NuGet adding these Assembly configs into on `<dependentAssembly>`.

If you make the above changes to `<runtime>`, your project should work.

Comment: Yes i believe i added the correct reference.  Ext.Net 2 directly from NuGet

Comment: Something is missing or misconfigured in your project setup. Maybe the following thread can help, see http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?16920&p=72510&viewfull=1#post72510

Comment: Maybe the following Web.config should be added as well, see http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?16920-CLOSED-2-0-MVC-3-Razor-Example&p=81696&viewfull=1#post81696

Comment: I've added my web.config above.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Pls do not use Nuget to get the Ext.Net dll.I believe the Ext.Net team do not update the Ext.Net dll in Nuget ASAP.Because i found the version is Nuget is 2.1.1.11828,it do not have Ext.Net.Mvc namespace.But the newest release version is 2.1.1.18233,it has Ext.Net.Mvc namespace...